# Allow users to use my online spreadsheet without saving their edits

Tags: google-sheets

I made an online spreadsheet to calculate grades. I want my users to use it without Google Sheets showing it real-time to other users.

How do I do this?

It seems if I allow people to edit the document, users will see other people interacting with the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this, but you can make it available to view, which will allow them to make a copy that they can then edit.

Comment: Oh. Do you know of other online applications that does what I want it to do?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is creating your own html form that will allow them to do the calculations. A form resembling something like an online mortgage calculator.

Answer (score -2):

You can try with SkyDrive if you want your users to use it without Google Docs showing it real-time to other users.

Comment: How does one have a Google Spreadsheet in SkyDrive, pray tell?